# Why webview header key converted in lowercase in android?

Tags: android, webview, http-headers

I am sending custom header in webview in android. When i am printing header parameter key and value in server, then parameter value print as it is, as it sent but parameter key is printing in lower case, but my requirement is to print parameter key as it is, as it sent. How can we achieve it?

below in my java code

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

headerValue = new HashMap<>();
   String headerKey = "A-Abc-Def-API-Version";
   headerValue.put(headerKey, "Abc");
   webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl, headerValue);
```

below is my PHP code

```
<?php
    echo "test";

$headers =  getallheaders();
foreach($headers as $key=>$val){
  echo $key . ': ' . $val . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Above code print header key as below

```
Accept:
a-abc-def-api-version: Abc
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP header name is case-insensitive. If your implementation requires case-sensitivity it violates the standard.

> 3.2.  Header Fields
>
> Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name
> followed    by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field
> value, and    optional trailing whitespace.

source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2

Comment: thanks for reply, but I am getting confuse that when we print it in IOS device it is printing as it is, as we are sending parameter key like "A-Abc-Def-API-Version : Abc". Is in IOS violates the standard?